# UIView having Animation from right to left

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

how to make uiview animated so it appears slowly from right to left and having two UIButtons on it having images on buttons and one of them image on button will change on button click

Comment: Are you really wishing an answer from Genie? show your efforts and code first.

Comment: Start reading documentation. Some pointers: [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/) [UIView animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f
                 animations:^ {
                     CGRect frame = YourView.frame;
                     frame.origin.x = 0;
                     YourView.frame = frame;
                     YourView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                     [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.3];
                     [UIView commitAnimations];
                 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code  and make changes according  to your requirements .
here i create a baseview which moves from right to left and vice versa.
In that baseview you put whatever u want to animate.
set bounceDistance,bounceDuration,animateWithDuration,delay variable according to your requirement.

```
-(IBAction)rightClicked:(id)sender {
    CGRect initalFrame = self.baseView.frame;
    initalFrame.origin.x = initalFrame.size.width;
   self.baseView.frame = initalFrame;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveFromLeftOrRight:) userInfo:@0 repeats:NO];
  }

-(IBAction)leftClicked:(id)sender {
   CGRect initalFrame = self.baseView.frame;
   initalFrame.origin.x = -initalFrame.size.width;
   self.baseView.frame = initalFrame;
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveFromLeftOrRight:) userInfo:@1 repeats:NO];
  }

-(void)moveFromLeftOrRight:(NSTimer *) timer {
    BOOL isLeft = [timer.userInfo boolValue];
    CGFloat bounceDistance = 10;
    CGFloat bounceDuration = 0.2;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
    animations:^{
     CGFloat direction = (isLeft ? 1 : -1);
     self.baseView.center = CGPointMake(self.baseView.frame.size.width/2 + direction*bounceDistance, self.baseView.center.y);}
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
     [UIView animateWithDuration:bounceDuration animations:^{ 
    self.baseView.center = CGPointMake(self.baseView.frame.size.width/2, self.baseView.center.y);
    }];
 }];
}
```

Comment: Great example !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are targeting iPhone.

- Set the view's x co ordinate to, say 320(max visible in iPhone) in the storyboard (IB).

  `x-320 y-0 width-320 height-568`
- In the viewDidAppear: you can animate and bring the view to the starting co ordinate, say 0. You can do this as follows

  ```
  -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];

       [UIView animateWithDuration:10.f animations:^{
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, 568.f);
       }];
  }
  ```

For the buttons you will have to be specific.

Comment: might be better to set your frame relative to your actual view. subview.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); as 568.0f height is for 4" iPhone only

Comment: It was just an example assuming the idea of animation is clear! You can read the very first line of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Right to Left animation & Left to right animation as-

```
        let firstViewTowardsLeft = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50))
        firstViewTowardsLeft.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(firstViewTowardsLeft)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {Bool in
            firstViewTowardsLeft.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)

        }, completion: nil)


        let secondViewTowardsLeft = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        secondViewTowardsLeft.backgroundColor = .red
        view.addSubview(secondViewTowardsLeft)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {Bool in
            secondViewTowardsLeft.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50)

        }, completion: nil)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate